# Flex tree won't show label, just the icon

Tags: apache-flex, tree

I get the folder icon, never the label.  I've tried numerous datasources, always the same thing.   File, ajax call, text, it always fails.

In the code below I even set a custom handler and watch the XML come in, I set a static text label going out.  Never anything shown.  This happens without the label function and using labelField.  Yes, I'm 100% sure the attribute matches.   Again, tried with numerous different datasources.

I don't know what would be obscuring the text, but not the icon.  But I checked for that as well.

Tried [this simple one file example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/wp-content/uploads/Tree_depthColors_test/bin/srcview/index.html), and it compiles fine.

Full code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:HGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">
<fx:Declarations>       
    <fx:XML id="selectedData2" source="assets/xml/orgchartmodel.xml"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   

        private function tree_labelFunc(item:XML):String {
            var label:String;

            label = "flexisshit";  //breakpoint hits here but I never see this text

            return label;
        }           
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Tree id="tree" dataProvider="{selectedData2}" labelFunction="tree_labelFunc" width="100%" height="100%"  showRoot="false" textDecoration="underline" textSelectedColor="0xFFCCFF" depthColors="[#FFFFFF, #EEEEEE, #DDDDDD, #CCCCCC, #BBBBBB, #AAAAAA]" />
</s:HGroup>
```

The XML file used above (only part shown)

```
<employee layout="default" name="Eric Joplin" email="ejoplin@yoyodyne.com" phone="555-0100" fax="555-0101" businessUnit="Management" status="present" gender="male">
<employee name="Gary Roberts" layout="left_below" email="groberts@yoyodyne.com" phone="555-0100" fax="555-0101" businessUnit="Logistics" status="present" gender="male">
<employee layout="default" name="Alexander Burns" email="aburns@yoyodyne.com" phone="555-0102" fax="555-0103" businessUnit="Logistics" status="present" gender="male"/>
<employee layout="default" name="John Conner" email="jconner@yoyodyne.com" phone="555-0104" fax="555-0105" businessUnit="Logistics" status="present" gender="male"/>
</employee>
<employe ....
```

Comment: are you embeding a font? because you would need to embed twice. Once for spark components, once for mx components.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Do I need to?   I've used flex in the past and don't seem to recall needing it for the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested out your code, it works for me so I'm guessing you have a css or some code somewhere that is embedding a font. Try setting the fontFamily to Verdana directly on the `mx:Tree`:

```
<mx:Tree id="tree"
         fontFamily="Verdana"
         width="100%" height="100%"
         textDecoration="underline"
         textSelectedColor="0xFFCCFF"
         dataProvider="{xmlListColl}"
         labelFunction="tree_labelFunc"
         showRoot="false"
         depthColors="[#FFFFFF, #EEEEEE, #DDDDDD, #CCCCCC, #BBBBBB, #AAAAAA]"
         />
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  This code was coming from outside my immediate control, that solved the problem.  Kudos to you.

Comment: Yes, that kind of thing has driven me crazy in the past as well.